# Amazon Web Service S3 timed out

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using `S3 bucket` to upload image from my `swift` project, however, every now and then my upload pauses and gives me the following warning in console. However, I am not sure why but the upload appears to automatically restart and the second time almost always succeeds. And any upload after that is normally fine. (It is only when I have not interacted with the server for awhile

```
AWSiOSSDK v2.4.7 [Error] AWSURLSessionManager.m line:212 | -[AWSURLSessionManager URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:] | Session task failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x13eba2b50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucketName/filename.jpg, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://s3.amazonaws.com/myBucketName/filename.jpg, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

**Below is how I send file to S3**

```
    // 2. Create upload request
let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadRequest.bucket = "myBucket"
uploadRequest.key = "FileName.jpg"
uploadRequest.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACL.PublicRead
uploadRequest.contentType = "image/jpg"
uploadRequest.body = url


// Track progress through an AWSNetworkingUploadProgressBlock
uploadRequest?.uploadProgress = {[weak self](bytesSent:Int64, totalBytesSent:Int64, totalBytesExpectedToSend:Int64) in
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

        let progress = Float(totalBytesSent) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToSend)

        print(" totalBytesSent \(totalBytesSent) / totalBytesExpectedToSend \(totalBytesExpectedToSend) progress = \(progress * 100 ) %")

        circularProgressView.setProgress(progress, animated: true)

    })
}

// 3. Upload to Amazone S3
let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
transferManager.upload(uploadRequest).continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task: AWSTask) -> AnyObject? in

    MRProgressOverlayView.dismissOverlayForView(self.view, animated: true)
    self.enableUserInteraction()

    if let error = task.error {

        if error.domain == AWSS3TransferUtilityErrorDomain {

            switch task.error?.code {
            case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType.Cancelled.rawValue?:
                break
            case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorType.Paused.rawValue?:
                break
            default:
                self.showErrorAlert("Error uploading image #1", message: "\(error)")
            }
        } else {
            self.showErrorAlert("Error uploading image #2", message: "\(error)")
        }

    } else {

        if task.completed {
            let imgLink = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/letzzeeamazones3bucket2/\(uploadRequest.key!)"
            self.postToFirebase(imgLink, userCoordinate: userCoordinate)

        } else {
            self.showErrorAlert("Error uploading image #3", message: "Please try again later")
            MRProgressOverlayView.dismissOverlayForView(self.view, animated: true)
            self.enableUserInteraction()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the simulator?

Comment: This happens both on my simulator and device

Comment: What is the question?  Timeouts are to be expected.  AWS could hide them from you, but they are showing you what is going on when they have too many requests to fulfill and too few available resources.  I use a Backblaze's b2 service and I see the same thing: timeouts from time to time.  Are these timeouts causing you a problem?

Comment: I understand your point. However, I see a few points that is odd. 1. This is a regular occurrence especially when I have not uploaded for an hour or so. 2. It automatically uploads the second time and it has never ever failed the second time. 3. If I upload something immediately after that, it always always succeeds. It is the patter that is weird, if it is a regular time out issue, I should not see this happen on a daily/hourly repeated pattern

Comment: Knowing nothing about swift, your error description in the comment sounds for me like some kind of authentication issue. Could be that some authentication token is cached, for that reason it works always with the second try, but the process to get this token in the first place takes longer. Maybe it is worthwhile exploring how the authentication mechanism works, and whether you can increase some timeout on the process which initially authenticates the request.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderKöb, that sounds like a good lead.

Comment: But.. if that is the case, wouldn't the upload never start rather than uploading  x% of the file, stop, restart, succeed.

Comment: Please check with the perimission of your bucket. I have faced certain issue with AWS3. please confirm the permission for the bucket .

Comment: Have you testing it by uploading with curl? I am pretty sure I had similar thing happen when I uploaded images from nodejs before. Was basically a network issue, but the files I was uploading were quite large. Another possibility is your network connection. Are you using a pocket wifi/cellular by any chance? Some of those have some really weird policies for large POST/PUT requests

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the Amazon AWS Mobile SDK displays an unclear warning in the console, turn on *verbose* logging to debug:

(Swift 4) `AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .verbose`

(Swift 3)
`AWSLogger.default().logLevel = .verbose`
(Swift 2) `AWSLogger.defaultLogger().logLevel = .Verbose`

…to reveal more information about what S3 buckets, regions, endpoints etc. are being used.

Comment: `AWSLogger` - deprecated. Use `AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .verbose`

Comment: (Swift 4) AWSDDLog.sharedInstance.logLevel = .verbose